# Help translation PYTHON to VB.NET

Tags: python, vb.net, multithreading, translation

I am coding an application in VB.NET that sends sms.

Would you please post **PYTHON->VB.NET** 
translation of this code and/or guidelines?

Thanks in advance!!!

```
import threading
class MessageThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,msg,no):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.msg = msg  # text message
        self.no  = no   # mobile number
    def run(self):
        # function that sends "msg" to "no"
        send_msg(msg,no) 

# records of users are retrived from database 
# and (msg,no) tuples are generated
records = [(msg1,no1),(msg2, no2),...(msgN,noN)] 

thread_list = []

for each in records:
    t = MessageThread(each)
    thread_list.append(t)

for each in thread_list:
    each.start()

for each in thread_list:
    each.join()
```

Comment: This code contains nothing substantial (it lacks send_msg()). Besides, for stuff like code translation, you should rather go to RentACoder or something like that.

Comment: Just put send_msg as it is whereever it belongs in the corresponding vb code.

Comment: Oh, if that's all you want to know, then your question should be "How do I call a function asynchronously in VB.NET", because that's all this piece of code does: call send_sms() asynchronously for each record (I think there's a typo though, it should be "MessageThread(*each)").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates a thread for every msg/no tuple and calls sendmsg. The first "for each ... each.start()" starts the thread (which only calls sendmsg) and the second "for each ... each.join()" waits for each thread to complete. Depending on the number of records, this could create a significant number of threads (what if you were sending 1000 SMS records) which is not necessarily efficient although it is asynchronous.

The code is relatively simple and pythonic, whereas for .NET you would probably want to use a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(VS.80).aspx) or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) to do the sendmsg calls. You will need to create a .NET class that is equivalent to the tuple (msg,no), and probably put the sendmsg() function in the class itself. Then create .NET code to load the messages (which is not shown in the Python code). Typically you would use a generic List<> to hold the SMS records as well. Then the ThreadPool would queue all of the items and call sendmsg.

If you are trying to keep the code as equivalent to the original Python, then you should look at [IronPython](http://www.ironpython.com/).

(The underscore in sendmsg caused the text to use italics, so I removed the underscore in my response.)

Answer (score 0):

This is IronPython-code ("Python for .NET"), hence the source code uses the .NET-Framework just as VB and all classes (even [System.Threading.Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)) can be used in the same way shown.

Some tips:

`MessageThread` derives from `Thread`, `msg` and `no` must be declared as class variables, `__init__` is the constructor, the `self`-parameter in the member functions isn't transcoded to VB (just leave it out). Use a `List<Thread>` for `thread_list` and define a little structure for the tuples in `records`.